# Change links in a page that match a certain regular expression with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

I want to change multiple links of my site but only if they match a regular expression.

Suppose one of the url contains a redirect with a value like:

```
http://www.website.com/?redirect=12345
http://www.website.com/?redirect=22345
http://www.website.com/?redirect=32345
```

The regex to match seems to be:

```
/redirect=*[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]/gi
```

And i wanted to replace the matches with a new value instead like:

```
http://www.website.com/?redirect=67890
```

But im not sure how to apply this to all the links on the pages as i haven't used regex for a long time. Would i need to use some kind of a for loop with document.getElementsByTagName("a") or can you apply to all urls directly with regex?

Comment: Well i am not too great with regular expressions but i know the match regex is something like "/redirect=*[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]/gi" but i am not sure how to apply it to all the links on the page as i don't use regex with JS that much.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: See my edit, i know the regex strings to match and replace but how can you apply them to all urls found on a page? I am guessing it involves using document.getElementsByTagName("a") but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need a loop to apply regex replace to all the links with pure JS.

```
for (var i = 0, links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), l = links.length; i < l; i++)
{
    links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(/\?redirect=\d+/, '?redirect=67890');
}
```

> declaring `links` and `l` as variable for the loop will cache their values while looping - it's a micro optimization.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i needed. Thanks